# Angularjs stateProvider not working with xampp. It only works with nodejs

Tags: php, angularjs, node.js, routes, xampp

I'm developing a blog in angularjs and PHP. Using nodejs everything worked perfectly, I could use "stateProvider" for routing the application. Now I am using xampp but when I insert in the url an address of the type "localhost / home / content" tells me "object not found", as if actually going to look for an object on the server instead of using the routing function of angularjs. If instead I insert "localhost / index_2.html" it actually shows me the page correctly and the url becomes "localhost / home / content" (as I expect it to be). How can I fix it? Thank you!

app.js

```
var importPath = "/partial/";
  var home = importPath+"home/";

  var homeContainer = home + 'homeContainer.html';
  var homeContent = home + 'homeContent.html';

  app.config(
    ["$stateProvider", "$urlRouterProvider", "$locationProvider",
      function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {

      $stateProvider
        .state('home', {
          templateUrl: homeContainer,
        })
        .state('home.homeContent', {
          url: '/home/content',
          templateUrl: homeContent,
        });


       $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/home/content");
       $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);


      }
    ]);

  app.run(['$rootScope', '$location',
      function ($rootScope, $location)
      {
        console.log("location ", $location.path());

      }
  ]);
```

index_2.html

```
......
<body>
...
<div ui-view></div>
...
</body>
```

Comment: could be that your `html5Mode` breaks the routing without a hash-bang (`#!`)

Comment: It is not about xampp or nodejs. It is about you use `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true)`

Comment: should not I use html5 mode? What's the purpose of html5 mode then? Thx

Comment: it removes hash-bang, turning URL from `www.website.com/#!/some/other/path` to `www.website.com/some/other/path`. Looks _professional_, but it breaks your routing, so you have to fix it manually (in `.htaccess` usually). If you can avoid it, then just don't use it. After removing it, make sure you have your links working: `href="/link"` should be `href="#!/link"`, etc. (with `ui.router` simply use states: `ui-sref="state"`)

Comment: thanks guys, I removed the html5 mode and now it works as it should.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments received, I was able to solve by removing the html5 mode and the tag `<base href="/">` in the index.html file.
Now the base url is `http: // localhost / #! / Home / content`